# Correct results showing, but I want to limit them to identical values

Tags: php, mysql, collation

I have this query which shows my "pages" in a dynamic table, however it shows all of the pages, I want to limit the "pages" to show only if their "campaignid" column matches that of the current "campaign", would anyone have any ideas.

This is the query that displays the data:

```
  $counter=1;               $userID=PageDB::getInstance()->get_user_id_by_name($_SESSION['user']);              $result=PageDB::getInstance()->get_pages_by_campaign_id($campaignID);
            $i=0;
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
                 $style = "";
                    if($i%2==0)
    {
        $style = ' style="background-color: #EFEFEF"';
    }
    echo "<tr".$style.">";
                echo "<td>" . htmlentities($row['pid']) . "</td>";
                echo "<td>". htmlentities($row['id']) . "</td>";
                ?>
                <td>
                <form style="display:none;"></form>
                    <form name="editPage" action="editPage.php" method="GET">
                        <input type="hidden" name="pageID" value="<?php echo $pageID = $row['pid']; ?>" />
                        <input type="submit" name="editPage"  value="<?php echo "Page "  . $counter; ?>" style="padding-top:4px; padding-bottom:6px;background:none;border:none; cursor:pointer"/>
                    </form> 
    </td>           
                <?php
                $pageID = $row['pid'];  
                $counter++;
                $i++;

                echo "</tr>\n";
            endwhile;
            mysqli_free_result($result);              
?>
```

And here is how I am querying the database.

```
public function get_pages_by_campaign_id($campaignID) {
    $campaignID = $this->real_escape_string($campaignID);
    return $this->query("SELECT pid,campaignid,id,campaign_name FROM pages,campaigns WHERE pages.campaignid = campaigns.id ORDER BY campaigns.id LIMIT 1,10");
    }
```

As I said it is returning the right data, but I only want to display the data where:
pages.campaignid = campaigns.id [1] or pages.campaignid = campaigns.id [r] etc...

Comment: Does the Campaigns table have a column to specify which is the current campaign, or even, a column to mark previous campaigns as complete? What I would do, is when adding a new campaign, you would update the previous campaigns for that user/page to set them as expired, which would allow you to use `where campaigns.expired = 0` to only show the current campaign.

Comment: I think I've found my issue, the page that leads onto this page/form is not parsing the campaign ID accross, so the form can't refference the campaign ID to begin with. Would anyone have suggestions about that?

Comment: Looking at your function `get_pages_by_campaign_id` your not using `where` to select the campaign. Try `$this->query("SELECT pid,campaignid,id,campaign_name FROM pages,campaigns WHERE pages.campaignid = campaigns.id where pages.campaignID = $campaignID ORDER BY campaigns.id LIMIT 1,10")`

Answer (score 0):

You need and additional `if-else` condition inside your `while` loop. This `if-else` statement will compare if current row is equal to campaigns.id

Comment: Ok, I'm hearing you, but this query was already out of my field of little expertise as is ... would you mind helping with an example?